# Less Code to Achieve this Effect?

Tags: c, string, performance, function, substring

I am working on some string manipulation functions, just out of my own interest. However, I may want to use these functions sometime in future code. I wrote the following to check if a substring exists within a string. I ran into a problem though. My program compares each char in both strings, however it had problems with out of order chars. It would take a long time to explain so I will just give an example:

if checking if "oobar" exists in the string "fooobar" my program would have trouble finding the location of the substrings because it would trip up on the first instances of the char 'o'
I developed a work around to this, but that's what it is a work around and not really a solid solution. So I was wondering if anybody could tell me how they would improve the following code (keep in mind I do NOT want to use any additional libraries):

```
int chksbstr(char *str, char *sbstr)
{
    int i, sbstrlen, strlen, p = 0;

for(i = 0; sbstr[i] != '\0'; i++);
sbstrlen = i;
for(i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++);
strlen = i;
if(sbstrlen > strlen)
{
    printf("\n**Error substring is larger than base string!");
    return 2;
}
if(sbstrlen == strlen)
{
    if(str == sbstr) return 0;
    else return 1;
}
for(i = 0; i <= strlen; i++)
{
    if(str[i] == sbstr[p]) p++;
    else if(str[i] != str[i - 1]) p = 0;
    if(p == sbstrlen) return 0;
}
return 1;
}
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm, are you looking for the "Naïve string search"?

Comment: `strstr` from the standard C library does this.

Comment: Look up the Boyer-Moore algorithm.

Comment: Get [CLRS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms) and read on the string matching chapter.

Comment: and the first two loops are `strlen`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursion can do this better. Oh, and by the way, descriptive identifiers are way better. There's no reason to randomly remove all the vowels, and don't forget `const`.

```
int check_substring(const char* str, const char* to_go, const char* substr) {
    if (*to_go == '\0') return 1; // Hit all
    if (*str == '\0') return 0; // Ran out of string to check
    if (*str == *to_go) return check_substring(str + 1, to_go + 1, substr);
    else {
        if (*str == *substr)
            return check_substring(str + 1, substr + 1, substr);
        else
            return check_substring(str + 1, substr, substr);
    }
}
int does_contain_substring(const char* str, const char* sbstr) {
    return check_substring(str, sbstr, sbstr);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much I wish I could vote this up but at the moment it says I don't have enough reputation so I will when I can, thanks again!

Comment: In fact I gotta thank you again, you just opened a whole new world of possibilities to me, I never knew how useful "return" can be thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

23 lines fewer:

```
if (strstr(baseString, subString) != NULL)
{
    /* contains */
}
```

Comment: (keep in mind I do NOT want to use any additional libraries):

Comment: You don't want to include stdio.h?

Comment: The OP seems to have put in some honest effort into writing his own `strstr` but hasn't succeeded though. He also states clearly inhis Qn that he doesn't need library functions. This answer simple mocks at his effort. Kindly guide new users if possible, else its better to refrain.

Comment: People don't usually consider the language's Standard library as an "additional" library.

Comment: @PavanManjunath I just saw your arrogant and irritating comment. How do you dare accusing me of mocking of the question? I 1. honestly thought OP didn't know about strstr 2. this  **is** an actual answer and solution.

Comment: @H2CO3 Its always the other way round. For me, your answer sounded rude and vice versa. I dint have any intention of irritating you. If you really thought the OP dint know about `strstr` you could have asked that in the comments as one person did in the comments. Your answer was posted after that comment. That is what made me put the comment I did. 

May be I misread your intentions. Sorry if that irritated you. 
Anyway, no point in dragging this argument. No ill will. Have a nice day!